# fslreorient2std could not find image

Tags: shell, ubuntu, image-processing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to reorient some images with `fslreorient2std` in an Ubuntu 20.4 shell running on Windows 10. I've installed WSL2 and FSL. When I run the command `fslreorient2std` in a directory where there is the image file (`.nii`), the following error message appear:

```sh
ERROR: Could not find image ws44891-153636-00001-00192-1.nii
```

See also below.

```sh
$ ls         
ws44891-153636-00001-00192-1.nii 

$fslreorient2std ws44891-153636-00001-00192-1.nii ws44891-153636-00001-00192-1_reorient.nii 

ERROR: Could not find image ws44891-153636-00001-00192-1.nii
```

I tried to download test images in other formats or test other `.nii` images I have, and the error is always the same.

I'd be grateful for any help, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. When I moved the required input file from the 'Volumes' directory to my local storage, it worked! I suspect it might be because 'flsreorient2std' couldn't read files in the 'Volumes' directory. If your files are also located in 'Volumes,' you could give this a try

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).